Inside a gke cluster how do i delete a specific image
I have created a cluster in gke and then create few deployments specific to my application. My question is how do i delete an specific image that has been up there because even though i have set my imagePullPolicy: Always in my deployment file it does not pull the latest image, instead it uses the cached image.
While i was working on my minikube i used to delete those images manually through this command minikube ssh -- docker rmi image-name
But in gke what is the exact procedure?
Also, i do want to know why it does not pull my latest image according to the imagePullPolicy: Always?

One challenge with manually deleting images cached by Kubernetes is that you would need to do this for each Node. If you're using Auto-Pilot, this may not be possible.
I've not tried this with GKE but, GKE defaults (!?) to containerd (container runtime) and so you should (!?) be able to use a tool such as ctr to connect to each Node's containerd socket, enumerate|delete cached images.

NOTE Garbage collection of Kubernetes container images is a valid problem. It is my understanding that GKE uses an automated garbage collection process for unused images. I use MicroK8s for development and use ctr to manually perform this process. Your question prompted me to better understand this and I learned that the kubelet does Garbage collection of unused containers and images

imagePullPolicy: Always should (as the documentation|name suggests) always pull images (from the repository) but this will only occur during Pod creation.
If you have an existing Pod, with imagePullPolicy: Always and you change update the image, no pull will occur. In this case, whacking (deleting) the Pod, should (!?) trigger the re-pull.
It is inadvisable to reuse image tags if the underlying image is changing.
Yes, during development, it becomes tedious to continually revise the tag on image changes but it is a good practice and should always be used in production.
It is better (though slightly more tedious) to always refer to an image by the image's digest (SHA-256 hash). The hash is very likely to change when the underlying image is changed and so this provides a (mostly) unique way to identify an image. Any change will require revising the image value and, on Pod recreation, the pull will always occur.
Instead of:
- image: foo:never-changed

You'd
- image: foo@sha256:123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0


(The Carvel kbld tool can query a Docker registry at deploy time and replace a floating image reference with a SHA-256 hash.)
